# ¿Cómo agregar Bootstrap a un proyecto React?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy empezando con ReactJS e intentando utilizar la librería de Bootstrap.

> Para instalar Bootstrap digité el siguiente comando:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

> Inserto código en HTML de Bootstrap en un componente como:

```
const CardComponent = () => {
    return(
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default CardComponent;
```

> Pero luego al correr el proyecto no me funciona la libreria de Bootstrap.

Comment: Existe una librería aparte que emula las funcionalidades de Boostrap en React llamada justamente "React Bootstrap". Te paso su documentación por si te interesa usarla [React Bootstrap - Introduction](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction).

Comment: Es porque te falta agregar el cdn en el archivo index.html que se encuentra en la carpeta public `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La solución que encontré fue agregar en el main del proyecto:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```